# COPY CSV files, then analyze? step by step?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, csv, import

I just started to upload CSV files and creating tables in the database of the company I work for. Would anyone be so kind to explain the proper steps to ensure the copy was complete and there are no mistakes?

My boss told me a few steps of how they do things:

CREATE TABLE -> COPY
or
INSERT DATA -> CREATE INDEX/CONSTRAINTS (if necessary) -> TABLE ANALYSIS

The table analysis part is the confusing part for me. They told me to **analyze the table, then check for errors, then get the estimate rows**. What do I do with the estimate rows? I used `ANALYZE table_name` but nothing really shows on the data output.

Please help!

Comment: [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) or [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'll want to check for a few things

- The number of rows inserted is consistent
- Data Types are sufficient (Ensure you didn't allocate too much or too little space to a variable)
- Data Types are consistent (I.e. You're using integer data types for integers if it's in the design)
- There weren't errors caused special characters (You shouldn't have this problem if you used a proper delimiter)

My assumption is "get estimate rows" is he simply wants the number of rows returned. I'll leave that up to you to figure out how to determine that.

If the CSV file was created correctly, I wouldn't sweat it too much. Don't be afraid to ask for help or advice from your colleagues, that's how you learn!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you Michael! This helped a lot!

Comment: i did. i guess i was just a bit paranoid. it actually wasn't that bad! still trying to understand how things work around here so i am definitely going to keep asking questions. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

My answer is going to take a slightly different tack.

Clearly your boss has given you instructions and you don't understand them. In my opinion it is important that you go back to your boss and keep asking questions until you understand.

There are a number of important reasons for this:
1. You understand what you are being asked to do (rather than us guessing).
2. If it goes wrong you have done what you were asked, and
3. You might learn something.

The attitude that asking questions ("asking noob questions again") makes you look stupid or ignorant is very dangerous and will, in fact, make you stupid and ignorant.

After 30 years developing some very complex software systems, I still ask questions whenever I don't understand something. The result? In the end, I understand.

This is the only way to actually get better. None of us was born knowing how to do everything.

Comment: i will. although i try to avoid it as much as possible by going online and doing my research first before i trouble them. but regardless, thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a big misunderstanding. Your boss probably just wants you to run

```
ANALYZE table_name;
```

for every table to update the statistics (including row estimates). The query planner uses those statistics to chose how to best execute queries. Read the fine manual about [**`ANALYZE`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html).
Better ask your boss next time if you don't understand instructions.